# Trailing slash in URL is considered a different page with different Like count?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

I've noticed that I get different *Like* numbers when I check a URL with or without a trailing slash.  It's logging them as separate URLS.

for example **WITH a slash**:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20total_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22jonahgoldstein.com/ahoy/%22

returns:

```
<fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
<link_stat>
<total_count>53</total_count>
</link_stat>
</fql_query_response>
```

and **WITHOUT the slash**:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20total_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22jonahgoldstein.com/ahoy%22

returns

```
<fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
<link_stat>
<total_count>68</total_count>
</link_stat>
</fql_query_response>
```

It would be wonderful if these pages weren't thought of as separate since my numbers will appear to people as half of what they should be.  I've noticed that Twitter's API doesn't have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can log this as a feature request [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs).  But url's with or without slashes are technically separate url's according to the http spec.  There is no way to fix this for existing share counts, but I would recommend setting up URL re-write on your web server to do a 301 redirect either to a url with or without a slash so this is avoided in the future.

Comment: gotcha.  too bad i didn't go with the .htaccess rewrite from the get go.  it's odd they don't just tally them together - i at least can't think of a scenario where it would be important to distinguish the two ... i.e. where a site owner would want the stats to be distinguished with/without a slash.  odd. thanks though.

Comment: Yep, that's the best solution for this I'd say.  Facebook doesn't seem to enforce canonicity so it's up to the web developer/admin to do so (if possible). Been looking into this myself today due to some perceived issues and it's a really interesting problem - we're planning on just collecting both values and combining them.  Interesting to note - this doesn't appear to happen at root level, just with sub-directories.